# What is the syntax for writing txt file with multiple numpy arrays+scalars and how to read it in again?

Tags: python, numpy, txt, data-files

I have 2 numpy arrays of same length lets call them A and B and 2 scalar values named C and D. I want to store these values into a single txt file. I thought of the following structure:

[image]

It doesnt have to have this format I just thought its convenient and clear. I know how to write a the numpy arrays into a txt file and read them out again, but I struggle how to write the txt file as a combination of arrays and scalar values and how to read them out again from txt to numpy.

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
C = [6]
D = [7]
np.savetxt('file.txt', (A, B))
A_B_load = np.loadtxt('file.txt')
A_load = A_B_load[0,:]
B_load= A_B_load[1,:]
```

This doesnt give me the same column structure that I proposed but stores the arrays in rows but that doesnt really matter.

I found one solution which is a bit unhandy since I have to fill up the scalar values with 0 for them to become of the same length like the arrays A and B there must be a smarter solution.

```
    A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    B = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
    C = [6]
    D = [7]
    fill = np.zeros(len(A)-1)
    C = np.concatenate((C,fill))
    D = np.concatenate((D, fill))
    np.savetxt('file.txt', (A,B,C,D))
    A_B_load = np.loadtxt('file.txt')
    A_load = A_B_load[0,:]
    B_load = A_B_load[1,:]
    C_load = A_B_load[2,0]
    D_load = A_B_load[3,0]
```

Comment: How do I ignore NaN while loading? Is saving NaN more storage efficient then 0s ? My arrays have length 2058

Comment: You can test it yourself. If I write a zero in a text file, it takes 2bytes, while nan takes 4bytes.

Comment: You could also use pandas DataFrame's method `.to_csv`. There, you have the option to write NaNs as an empty string. Or you could convert your arrays to string arrays and replace NaNs with empty strings.

Comment: A good `csv` has a consistent number of columns for each row.  That's not your proposed layout.

Comment: @hpaulj OP was just interested in a `.txt` file having the smallest size and containing the values he listed in the question. You instead repeat scalar values `n` times just to get a _good_ `csv`. You should at least say why it is better to have a _good_ `csv`, other than purism. The fact that pandas' method is called `to_csv` does not imply that it can just be used to write `csv`s. Notice how OP never wrote anything about `csv` at all, and now you're basing your answer on that. Other than that, ok, your answer works as well, as many other implementation would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [123]: A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
     ...: B = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
     ...: C = [6]
     ...: D = [7]
```

`savetxt` is designed to write a 2d array in a consistent csv form - a neat table with the same number of columns in each row.

```
In [124]: arr = np.stack((A,B), axis=1)
In [125]: arr
Out[125]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 1]])
```

Here's one possible write format:

```
In [126]: np.savetxt('foo.txt', arr, fmt='%d', header=f'{C} {D}', delimiter=',')
     ...: 
In [127]: cat foo.txt
# [6] [7]
1,5
2,4
3,3
4,2
5,1
```

I put the scalars in a header line, since they don't match with the arrays.

`loadtxt` can recreate that `arr` array:

```
In [129]: data = np.loadtxt('foo.txt', dtype=int, skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
In [130]: data
Out[130]: 
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 1]])
```

The header line can be read with:

```
In [138]: with open('foo.txt') as f:
     ...:     header = f.readline().strip()
     ...:     line = header[1:]
     ...: 
In [139]: line
Out[139]: ' [6] [7]'
```

I should have saved it as something that's simpler to parse, like '# 6,7'

Your accepted answer creates a dataframe with `nan` values and blanks in the csv

```
In [143]: import pandas as pd
In [144]: df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(arr) for arr in [A,B,C,D]], axis=1)
     ...: df.to_csv("test.txt", na_rep="", sep=" ", header=False, index=False)
In [145]: df
Out[145]: 
   0  0    0    0
0  1  5  6.0  7.0
1  2  4  NaN  NaN
2  3  3  NaN  NaN
3  4  2  NaN  NaN
4  5  1  NaN  NaN
In [146]: cat test.txt
1 5 6.0 7.0
2 4  
3 3  
4 2  
5 1
```

Note that `np.nan` is a float, so some of the columns are float as a result.  `loadtxt` can't handle those "blank" columns; `np.genfromtxt` is better at that, but it needs a delimiter like `,` to mark them.

Writing and reading the full length arrays is easy. But mixing types gets messy.

Here's a format that would be easier to write and read:

```
In [149]: arr = np.zeros((5,4),int)
     ...: for i,var in enumerate([A,B,C,D]):
     ...:     arr[:,i] = var
     ...: 
In [150]: arr
Out[150]: 
array([[1, 5, 6, 7],
       [2, 4, 6, 7],
       [3, 3, 6, 7],
       [4, 2, 6, 7],
       [5, 1, 6, 7]])
In [151]: np.savetxt('foo.txt', arr, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
In [152]: cat foo.txt
1,5,6,7
2,4,6,7
3,3,6,7
4,2,6,7
5,1,6,7
In [153]: np.loadtxt('foo.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=int)
Out[153]: 
array([[1, 5, 6, 7],
       [2, 4, 6, 7],
       [3, 3, 6, 7],
       [4, 2, 6, 7],
       [5, 1, 6, 7]])
```

Answer (score 1):

A smarter solution could be to use pandas instead of numpy (if that is an option for you):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(arr) for arr in [A,B,C,D]], axis=1)
df.to_csv("test.txt", na_rep="", sep=" ", header=False, index=False)
a = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=" ", header=None).values
```

The first line creates a dataframe by concatenating all your arrays. Pandas' default behaviour is to replace missing values with NaNs. The second line writes the output file replacing NaNs by an empty string (as you seem to care about the file size). The last line gives you a numpy array:

```
In [45]: a
Out[45]: 
array([[ 1.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 2.,  4., nan, nan],
       [ 3.,  3., nan, nan],
       [ 4.,  2., nan, nan],
       [ 5.,  1., nan, nan]])
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since your input was of integer type,

```
In [20]: A.dtype
Out[20]: dtype('int64')
```

more precisely a `64-bit signed integer`, you may want to get the same type back.

To get that, just do:

```
a = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=" ", header=None).fillna(0).astype(np.int)
```

So you first replace NaNs with zeros as you don't use those values anyway, and transform everything directly to `np.int` (pandas' `Int64` would support `NA` values, but then you should transform your arrays to numpy's `int64` again, so it's not worth it).

You will get a pandas `DataFrame`:

```
In [63]: a
Out[63]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  5  6  7
1  2  4  0  0
2  3  3  0  0
3  4  2  0  0
4  5  1  0  0
```

From which you can easily get back your arrays:

```
A = a[0].to_numpy(); B=a[1].to_numpy(); C=a.iloc[0,2]; D=a.iloc[0,3]
```